# Removing duplicates from a recommendation

Tags: algorithm, architecture, filtering, recommendation-engine

I am building a recommendation System which recommends short videos like TikTok. how do I efficiently filter out the videos already viewed by the user?

one thing I can think of is I can track the videos for each user into a mongo Document and before recommending the videos I can check in this document if its present, but this won't be a scalable solution.

What could be a better way?

Answer (score -1):

Set intersection is a very old algorithm, don't write your own, use whatever is available in your language/framework/etc.

[Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashset-contains-method-in-java/)

[.Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?view=net-5.0)

[JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has)

Every other language will have some equivalent.  Use it, it will be more optimized than anything you can devise.  From a data-standpoint, yes, store a list of videos the user has viewed, pull those into a set, check your recommendations against that set.